# Addition of two Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is the vector space of $n$-dimensional matrices, $U$ is the subspace of lower triangular matrices and $W$ is the subspace of diagonal matrices, would it be correct to say that:

\begin{align}
U\cap W=W\\
U+W=U
\end{align}

?

Comment: yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, consider that $ W \subset U$.